# Ionic 2 ngIf not update after login

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

I have issue with `*ngIf` in ionic 2 . Here is my code

```
<div  *ngIf="isLogin" class="profile-info ng-binding padding text-center" (click)="openPage(accountPage)">
        {{userEmail}}
         <span menu-toggle="menu-toggle" class="cl-primary">
           <ion-icon name="md-create"></ion-icon>
          (Edit)</span>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="!isLogin" (click)="openPage(loginPage)" class="menu-item">
        <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
        Login
    </div>
```

Nothing happen after i back from login page because of `*ngIf`

If i remove ngIf like this code , userEmail will display correctly

```
 <div class="profile-info  padding text-center" (click)="openPage(accountPage)">
        {{userEmail}}
         <span menu-toggle="menu-toggle" class="cl-primary">
           <ion-icon name="md-create"></ion-icon>
          (Edit)</span>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="!isLogin" (click)="openPage(loginPage)" class="menu-item">
        <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
        Login
    </div>
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

Correct your HTML as below as you forgot to add `*` in first `ngIf` condition:

```
<div *ngIf="isLogin" class="profile-info ng-binding padding text-center" (click)="openPage(accountPage)">
  {{userEmail}}
  <span menu-toggle="menu-toggle" class="cl-primary">
    <ion-icon name="md-create"></ion-icon>(Edit)
  </span>
</div>
<div *ngIf="!isLogin" (click)="openPage(loginPage)" class="menu-item">
   <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>Login
</div>
```

Comment: thank your answer , 

my mistake when post the question but it doesn't work with *ngIf

Comment: if it did not work then it means that `isLogin` is not set to `true` after login.check your component code and if possible share it here

Answer (score 1):

Just use *ngIf instead of ngIf.

Comment: thank your answer , 

my mistake when post the question but it doesn't work with *ngIf